# Threading Issue; how to implement properly?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, performance, splash-screen

I have a program where I have lots of tasks going on during a splash screen. Obviously I want to make it as fast as possible, and the best solution I have found from the web is to do multithreading.

The problem is I don't know if I'm implementing them correctly, and I'm getting confused. I'm looking for some webcams on my network, and I have a different protocol for each brand. So I have a different class for each brand. I want to look for multiple brands at the same time to speed it up:

```
 Public Shared workingCamList As New List(Of NetworkSearch.camera)  
 Public Shared Function findCameras(ByRef cameraList As List(Of NetworkSearch.camera)) As List(Of NetworkSearch.camera)

    workingCamList.Clear()

    Dim brand1Thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf FindFirstBrandCam)
    Dim brand2Thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf FindSecondBrandCam)


    brand1Thread .Start(workingCamList)
    brand2Thread .Start(workingCamList)

    'wait
    brand1Thread .Join()
    brand2Thread .Join()


    Return workingCamList
End Function
```

But instead of starting brand1 and then brand 2 and me just waiting until they're both done, the join function(s) wait and go through them one by one. They're also both returning the camera struct to the same list, so I'm trying to prevent a race condition as well. I'm okay with creating two different lists and joining them.

How do I start the two threads and then wait until they're both done? I'm looking to expand also to a larger number of threads.

Comment: Multi-threading will not make it any faster. It will just allow you to perform a task in the background whilst the splash screen is giving some feedback to the user.

Comment: So, if I wanted to do two tasks at once and wait for them to both be done, it won't make it faster with mulithreading. What's a better way to do it?

Comment: If you have a speed issue in your application then you need a profiler to see what is taking the time and try and make that more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN "Thread.Join()    Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates, while continuing to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping."

If you'd like to have both run at the same time and wait for them both to be finished, create a boolean for each thread that your threaded functions can both see, in each function make sure to set these booleans to "True" once they are done, and then loop until both of those are true.

```
' somewhere FindFirstBrandCam and FindSecondBrandCam can access and your function can access
Dim finishedFindFirstBrandCam as Boolean = False
Dim finishedFindSecondBrandCam as Boolean = False


'in your function (partial code)
brand1Thread .Start(workingCamList)
brand2Thread .Start(workingCamList)

'instead of .join() for each thread
Do Until (finishedFindFirstBrandCam  And finishedFindSecondBrandCam )
    Application.DoEvents()
Loop

Return workingCamList
```

The boolean method works for a small number of threads, to expand to n threads, you could track an integer value, which all of the threads increment when they are done (be sure to use a Lock with that (SyncLock in vb.net) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t.aspx, otherwise you can have problems). Loop until the integer value equals the number of threads that needs to have finished.

Comment: Cool! I'll try it and see how it does in the profiling.

Comment: -1 The use of DoEvents is discouraged at best. Plus there is absolutely no need to use DoEvents if you are using threads to do the work. It kind of defeats the point.